# WebBrowser click element <button>

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have an application that does some posts on a blog. The blog went through change and where was the `<href>` passed to `<button type = "submit" value = "Post" class = "btn btnD medBtn MFSM touchable"`

And the code that used no longer works, follows my code;

```
var links = br.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{

    if ((link.InnerText != null) && ((link.InnerText.Contains("Publicar"))||(link.InnerText.Contains("Discussão")  )))
    {
        link.InvokeMember("click");

    }
}
```

I've tried to search the button element but does not work;

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = br.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("class").Contains("btn btnD medBtn MFSM touchable"))
    {
        element.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```